# how to move particular item gridview in android

Tags: android, gridview, gridview-sorting

i have developed  gallery page using GridView with alphabetical Index Based Sorting.

initially it's show alphabet order .

now my requirement is when user click Z  , grid view move to Z staring position

Comment: You need to update the data structure passed to adapter. Sort data according to column selected and reset the adapter.

Comment: but ,my requirement  X content is same place

Comment: can i know code of assigning adapter to gridview and array adapter used